# Select 2 drop-down input search doesn't work inside bootstrap popup modal

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$('#selectList').change(function() {
    var opval = $(this).val();
    if(opval=="secondoption"){
        $('#maint').modal("show");
    }
});  

  $('.select2').select2();
```

```html
<form id='selectList'>

            <select class="selsm-3 inblock-3 select2"  onClick="showSelected(this)">
               <option value="" >Select</option>
                                       
                                        <optgroup label="Secondary Income" class="purpose">
                                            <option value="secondoption">maintenance</option>
                         
            </select>
        </form>

  <!--Modal for Submit button page Start-->
<div id="maint" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="maintLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      <div class="modal-header modhead"><h4 class="modal-title" align="center">Application Saved Successfully!</h4></div>
      
      <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                
        Application ID : 1704200001<br><br>
        
        Thank You!!
        
                       
       </div>
       
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
    
        <div align="center" style="margin-right: 100px;">
        <a href="">
        <button type="button" class="btn clear" data-dismiss="modal"  onclick="showhide('postsavedetails','block'), showhide('savetoproceed','none')" align="center">Close</button></a>
        
        </div>
      </div>
   
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!--Modal for Submit button page End-->
```

I am using the Bootstrap pop-up modal and select2 js dropdown inside it, Select 2 is working fine when used outside the pop-up modal, but when used inside pop-up modal, as shown in the bwlo image, dropdown is working, but search input is not working.